# reloading vimrc causes different syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

When I open up a file in macvim it is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCxmo.jpg.
I have set `,V` to `:source ~/.vimrc<CR>`.

After I have this file open, I press `,V`, and the syntax highlighting changes to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn9Ia.jpg.
The difference is that `(`,`)`,`;`,`,` become from blue, white, and `->`,`.`,`?` become from blue, darker blue.
Why does that happen? This is my vimrc file https://gist.github.com/pvinis/4979592

--
Update: I found out that `Valloric/vim-operator-highlight` is the plugin that changes the colors. so the first picture is the correct picture.
I also found out, that as soon as i do `:syntax on`, the colors reset. Is there a way to check if syntax is already on?

Comment: What does `:set background?` show before and after you do `,V`?

Comment: dark on both. is there some way i can export everything that's set, and see the differences afterwards?

Comment: You can use `:set` and `:hi` to list settings and syntax highlighting. [This tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor) might also help with debugging.

Comment: i used `:set` and got the list before and after. the extra thing before is `formatoptions=croql`, and after, there was no `formatoptions`. i have on my vimrc `formatoptions-=ct`, and this causes `formatoptions` to completely disappear?

Comment: sorry, checked it again, and after, it's `formatoptions=q`

Comment: There are some auto commands when you read the file, when you enter the window etc. when first opening VIM. And these are not run again when reloading `.vimrc` as far as I know. Try doing `:e` after reloading, is it ok then?

Comment: I also did `:hi` before and after. before, there was `OperatorChars xxx guifg=cyan` and after there was `OperatorChars xxx cleared`. How can I find out what messes with that?

Comment: Try `:verb hi operatorchars`.

Answer (score 5):

## Problem:

When reloading `.vimrc`, some highlight groups are messed up.
It depends on what plugins you have and what colorschemes you are using.
I've noticed that some `highlight links` were broken, and some `highlight groups` were cleared.

#### Affected highlight groups

In my particular setup I've noticed broken `hi links` or  cleared `groups` on:

- `SignColumn`
- [`GitGutter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) (which uses `SignColumn`)
- [`powerline-status`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) (which uses status line)

**Notice the affected areas after reloading:**
(reloading means saving the modified file. Using `:wa` in this example)
[image: Reloading mess!]

## Solution

Unfortunately the listed answers or any combination of options that I've tried does not preserve or reinstate the `hi` groups after reloading.
Running manually `colorscheme <your-coloscheme>` after reloading fixes everything, but when doing it with `Vimscript` it does not.
Hopefully someone will share a proper solution to this annoying small issue.

## Ugly hack

### Reloading vimrc:

On any change to my vim config files, I execute `reload.vim`:
**.vimrc:**

```
" .....
augroup reload_vimrc " {
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost ~/.vim/*.vim,~/.vim/vimrc source ~/.vim/reload.vim
augroup END " }
```

### `reload.vim`: restores broken links and cleared groups

What we have to do is to reinstate the `hi` groups after sourcing `vimrc`.
To find the correct values for an affected area, e.g. for `SignColumn`, type:
`:hi SignColumn`, *BEFORE* any reloading has occurred.

**The outcome is (where `xxx` is a preview):**
[image: hl SignColumn]

You have to do this for every affected `hi`.
In the following snippet I initially fix `SignColumn` to match my `solarized` colorscheme.
Then I fix some `GitGutter` color issues:
e.g., `GitGutterAdd` is linked to `GitGutterAddDefault` which is preserved, but from `GitGutterAddDefault` to `DiffAdd` is broken, so I reinstall that one. And so on so forth.

**reload.vim:**

```
source ~/.vim/vimrc

hi SignColumn ctermfg=12 ctermbg=0 guifg=Cyan guibg=Grey

" GitGutterAdd -> GitGutterAddDefault (preserved)
hi link GitGutterAddDefault DiffAdd

" GitGutterChange -> GitGutterChangeDefault (preserved)
hi GitGutterChangeDefault ctermfg=3 ctermbg=0 guifg=#bbbb00

" GitGutterDelete -> GitGutterDeleteDefault (preserved)
hi GitGutterDeleteDefault ctermfg=1 ctermbg=0 guifg=#ff2222

" GitGutterChangeDelete -> GitGutterChangeDefault (preserved)
" (which we already fixed above)

" Powerline highlight groups
" (see this attached Gist for solution)
```

**Everything works as it should:**
[image: Fix hi groups and links]

### Fixing [`powerline-status`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) colors:

This one is a bit more tricky, but the principle is the same. All highlight groups of `powerline` start with `Pl_`. But some of them might not exist yet. For example, if you haven't entered `visual` mode yet, then the respective groups for visual mode won't be populated yet. So, enter `insert`, `visual`, and `normal` modes to populate the groups and then copy them. You can find them at the bottom of the output of the `hl` command. Then, paste them in your `reload.vim` and adapt them to be legit `hl` commands.

It may sound like a lot of work but it isn't.
Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Paschalis/c3eaafe83893cddd2b0c04aab9559b69) with the full `reload.vim`, and some `gifs` to guide you through.

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour as what you describe, thank you for putting up this answer. Is there still not a way to fix this? And do you understand why `colorscheme xyz` works when run manually but not in a script?

Comment: I posted an answer with a workaround that worked for me. Perhaps it will work for you too?

Answer (score 3):

I had something very similar to this happening. I was able to solve it by making sure these were in the correct order:

```
syntax on
let g:solarized_termtrans=1
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

I also used this for reloading

```
augroup reload_vimrc
autocmd!
autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
augroup END
```

With those two I could do live updating of my vimrc without having to reload. I am using iTerm2 with Terminal vim. Hopefully this helps someone else out as I have spent quite a bit of time trying to get this live reloading working. Also make sure you have the newest versions of the solarized theme. I know it seems mundane to mention but it might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the highlightings are defined / changed by some plugin. The re-execution of `:colorscheme` resets those definitions. The plugins would have to hook into the `ColorScheme` event with an `:autocmd`, but most don't.

To work around this, try wrapping the `:colorscheme` in a guard:

```
if ! exists('g:colors_name') || g:colors_name !=# 'Tomorrow-Night-Eighties'
    colorscheme Tomorrow-Night-Eighties
endif
```

Comment: Then try to nail down which line in your .vimrc causes this. You can do binary search: Delete / comment out one half, repeat with other if no change, then split the problematic half and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
"auto reload vimrc once changed
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd! BufWritePost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC

  " This fixes the color changes and things not working :D
  autocmd! BufWritePost .vimrc filetype plugin indent on
endif
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Have a look at my reload function on github: 
https://github.com/voyeg3r/dotfaster/blob/c64ec563802de2942abd1e9a8bb2639ca1f09f10/nvim/init.vim#L732-L742

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea why, (probably for the same reason that doing `:source ~/.vimrc` manually works) but for me replacing

```
autocmd BufWritePost *vimrc,*exrc :source %
```

with

```
autocmd BufWritePost *vimrc,*exrc :call feedkeys(":source %\<cr>")
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`autocmd BufWritePost *vimrc,*exrc :call feedkeys(":source %\<cr>")`

Fixed it right away for me.  Must be some weird issue with the ordering.  I also have a keystroke to resource the file and this *always* works even when the autocmd was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely unrelated to your particular case, but I had a similar problem so I thought I'd share since it's the first StackOverflow result on Google.

My issue with reloading was in two phases: using the dark Solarized theme, reloading `.vimrc` would first change the colors slightly, then, reloading a second time, it would switch to the light Solarized theme.

The lines about colors in my `.vimrc` were:

```
set background="dark"
let g:solarize_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

The problem? The first line shouldn't have quotes:

```
set background=dark
```

I can now reload `.vimrc` without changing the colors. I'm not sure why it would work one time and work a different way after though. I realized that after commenting out everything but these lines as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

set `syntax enable` after `colorscheme`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.